# onclick load {% include 'test.html' %}

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I would like to load Jinja2 templating string when user clicks on an element. 
for example I have tags like:

```
 <div class="one"><a href="#one">One</a></div>
 <div class="two"><a href="#two">Two</a></div>
 <div class="three"><a href="#three">Three</a></div>
```

only after clicking on One, I must load the bellow string:

```
{% include 'one.html' %}
```

and after clicking on Two, this string must be loaded:

```
{% include 'two.html' %}
```

and so on.
How can I manage this issue? Dynamic content loading when clicking

Comment: Keep in mind that JavaScript happens in the browser (client) and, if I'm not mistaken, Jinja2 is python ten plating that will happen on the server. Showing the template string via JavaScript will achieve nothing. You will either need to load all of the items when the page is served and then display them on click, or you will need an Ajax solution that will fetch the template result and insert it on click.

Comment: Thank sirReal, Yes you are right I am using python-Flask and it doesn't allow that method to be implemented. The only thing is that I would like to only execute the Jinja2 string like {% include 'one.html' %} when clicking on a div and as you told I guess Agax can overcome that issue. Thank you

Comment: My pleasure. I've provided a slightly more elaborate *answer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that JavaScript happens in the browser (client-side), while Jinja2 is python-based templating which will occur server-side. Showing the template string via JavaScript will not achieve your desired result. There seem to be two ways of achieving what you want.

One option is to output the result of the template when the page loads initially and then display it through some javascript behavior. There are many jQuery plugins to achieve this result, one example you may look at is [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Another option, if you don't wish to produce all of the template results when you first load the page, would be to load the result of the templates via ajax. The ajax request would need have to be served the result of the desired jinja2 template which can then be output into your page. [jQuery's load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) provides a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use some JavaScript to achieve that.

One solution is to use jQuery load http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Dear Kamil, Thank you for yuor responce, but the load method does not work in here, since I am using python microframework Flask and it does not allow loading html document via url.